# Changing cite name in .bib files generated from Mendeley

Tags: bibtex

I would like to customize the code names of the articles I cite since AuthorDate does not work for me. I usually give specific names to every paper because I often cite up to 6 papers from same author.

The problem is that Mendeley keeps renaming the citing code words periodically (updating the .bib file). Is there a way to change this? I would like to keep the code names I personally create since i can easily remember them which makes the writing faster.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the Citation Key in Mendeley to whatever you prefer. You may have to enable this view, by going to the menu->Tools->Options->Document Details, then choose the document type (for instance, Journal Article), then check the Citation Key box. Then, a field for Citation Key should be visible in the details pane on the right hand side of the window.

Alternatively, you will have to copy the `.bib` file to a different location and maintain it separately.

[image: Options Box]
[image: Document Pane]

Comment: How do I do this if I only have the webbrowser version?