# Write latex with Mendeley "integration"

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, overleaf

Hi i was wondering what is the fastes workflow might be for citing in writelatex with new the Mendeley integration.

For those who are unfamiliar with writelatex and mendeley integration; writelatex generates a .bib file based on my complete Mendeley library, which is quite large. The .bib file is then placed conveniently in a project folder and linked directly to my Mendeley library. While in writelatex the .bib can be easily accessed as a popup screen, but searching within the .bib is limited to highlighting search words(meaning it does not "go-to"). After scrolling through 2000 lines i usually find the specific bibtex key i am looking for and manually type \cite{key}, but this is a very time consuming experience.

Any suggestions as to how the optimal workflow is intended?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Check this link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180059/32374 Can you have Mendeley open separately?

Comment: Thanks, currently i think the easiest way is to search for key words in Mendeley then just enter lead authors last name + year and hope that is the correct key.. hopefully they will add a couple of functions in writelatex

Comment: Writelatex founder here: we're in the process of releasing an inline fuzzy search that will auto-populate from your .bib file as you type \cite{abc...}. Should be released this week!

Comment: Sounds very helpfull - thanks for a great application.